# Unquoting an item in a quasiquoted dotted pair

Tags: scheme

I've started trying to learn the innards of Scheme evaluation, and one aspect of quasiquotation, unquoting, evaluation and cons-cells is confusing me. If you can recommend any good references on the subject I'd be very grateful.

The R7RS draft has this example in section 4.2.8 on quasiquotation.

```
`(( foo ,(- 10 3)) ,@(cdr '(c)) . ,(car '(cons)))
```

(It's in the R4RS spec too, so this isn't a new thing.)

According to the spec this should evaluate to:

```
((foo 7) . cons)
```

I'm having some trouble understanding why. To my mind, the . removes the unquote from the start of the inner list, meaning it won't be evaluated as a procedure.

Here's a simpler expression that demonstrates the same problem:

```
`(foo . ,(car '(bar)))
```

Using the same logic as above, this should evaluate to:

```
(foo . bar)
```

And indeed it does evaluate to that on the Scheme systems I've tried.

However, to my understanding it shouldn't evaluate to that, so I want to find out where I'm going wrong.

My understanding of Scheme evaluation is (OK, simplified) if it's the first keyword after an open-bracket, call that procedure with the remainder of the list as the parameters.

My understanding of the spec is that ',' is exactly equivalent to wrapping the next expression in an '(unquote' procedure.

My understanding of the dot notation is that, for general display purposes, you remove the dot and opening parenthesis (and matching closing parenthesis), as described here:

> [In general, the rule for printing a pair is as follows: use the dot
>   notation always, but if the dot is immediately followed by an open
>   parenthesis, then remove the dot, the open parenthesis, and the
>   matching close parenthesis.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html)

So:

```
`(foo . ,(car '(bar)))
```

Could equally be rendered as:

```
(quasiquote (foo unquote (car (quote (bar)))))
```

(In fact, this is how [jsScheme](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/jsscheme/) will render the input in its log window.)

However, when it comes to evaluating this:

```
(quasiquote (foo unquote (car (quote (bar)))))
```

Why is the 'unquote' evaluated (as a procedure?), unquoting and evaluating the (car...) list? Surely it should just be treated as a quoted symbol, since it's not after an opening bracket?

I can think of a number of possible answers - 'unquote' isn't a regular procedure, the 'unquote' is evaluated outside of the regular evaluation process, there's a different way to indicate a procedure to be called other than a '(' followed by the procedure's symbol - but I'm not sure which is right, or how to dig for more information.

Most of the scheme implementations I've seen handle this using a macro rather than in the same language as the evaluator, and I'm having difficulty figuring out what's supposed to be going on. Can someone explain, or show me any good references on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that there are macros involved: in particular, `quasiquote` is a macro, and `unquote` and `unquote-splicing` are literals. None of those are procedures, so normal evaluation rules do not apply.

Thus, it's possible to give `(quasiquote (foo bar baz unquote x))` the special treatment it needs, despite `unquote` not being the first syntax element.